# How to find marginal CDF from joint PMF?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

If I have the joint PMF:
$$P_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0.01, & x,y=1,2,3,\ldots,10 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$
How would I proceed if I want to find $F_X(x)$ from here? I now this equation:
$$F_X(x) = \lim_{y \to \infty} F_{X,Y}(x,y)$$
But how do I find the joint CDF from the joint PMF?

Comment: Did you intend $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ (with capital $X,Y$ in the sunscript and lower-case $x,y$ as the arguments? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I've corrected it

Comment: Not quite. You still have a limit as $y\to\infty$ of a function that does not depend on $y. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry, didn't realise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that your joint pmf is the product of 2 independent uniform ([discrete uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution)) distributions thus

$$P(X=x)=\frac{1}{10}$$

for $X \in \{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$

... in this case it is easier to find the marginal pmf first and then sum it to get its CDF